# Why does layout_gravity set to left/right have no effect in horizontal LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, textview

I am trying to have two `TextView`s one to the left side of the parent and the other to the right.
I was expecting that `layout_gravity` would be enough to do the trick.
But it doesn't work. Example code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LEFT"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RIGHT"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That seems to work but why do I need to define gravity and weight? I thought `layout_gravity` sets the position within the parent. `gravity` is only for text (content). Can you please explain?

Comment: You want the two texts to be evenly distributed half and half; that is why we need to use weights here. We also need to set width to zero (0) because the orientation is horizontal. Weights puts each item on its place (Right & Left). Gravity positions items within its desired position.

Comment: I thought that `layout_gravity` right positions the `TextView` to the right of the parent. Seems I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: When you use weights, you are creating 2 sides that are equal here. Now, on each of those sides, you can use gravity attribute to again position the item (either start, center or end). Each side has the ability to be positioned accordingly.

Comment: I understand how weights work and I thought about using that only as a workaround or "dirty hack". I thought that only `layout_gravity` should be sufficient since it is about positioning the view within the parent

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` doesn't use `layout_gravity` for the orientation it is laying out. You could use `layout_gravity` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` to control how they are place vertically: top, centre or bottom.

You could change your `LinearLayout` to vertical, then your left/right gravities would work, but the second `TextView` would be placed further down than the first one. I assume this is not what you want.

It seems to me you are not interested in the layout logic that `LinearLayout` provides (which is placing it's children one after the other). You want just one to be left aligned and one right aligned. You can use gravity for that effect if you put your `TextView`s in a `FrameLayout` instead.

Comment: So do you mean it ignores it?

Comment: I am gonna have to read more on this; @Marcin, please provide documentation for this?

Comment: @Jim I've extended my answer, to explain how `layout_gravity` is used by `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Eenvincible to be fair documentation doesn't really cover it. Try it out in a sample app, set different configurations of parent layouts and layout_gravity values. Or read the source code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :
Editing Eenvincible's Answer...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```